# How can this function possibly ever be greater than another?

Tags: calculus, integration

Say I have two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I know that $f(x)' = 1$, and $g(x)' = (x + 1)^{-a}$, where a is some constant $0 < a < 1$.

As you can see, $g'(x)$ is always less than or equal to one, and therefore always less than or equal to $f'(x)$ (to the right of the y-axis, of course).

As far as I can tell, through integration, $f(x) = x$, and $g(x) = \frac{(x + 1)^{(1-a)}}{1-a}$. The problem here, is that for some values, $g(x) > f(x)$ in this case. How can this possibly be?

If a function's derivative is less than some other function's at all points, how can that function ever be greater than it?

[Example graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jmvstmtxlm) (I had to replace $f'(x)$ with $f(x)$, $g'(x)$ with $g(x)$, $f(x)$ with $h(x)$, and $g(x)$ with $j(x)$ due to desmos not supporting prime notation.

Comment: You can add constants to a function without changing the derivative

Comment: Even though $g$ is slower than $f$, it might have a head start. Take a look at a simpler example: $f(x)=2x,g(x)=x+1$.

Comment: $x\mapsto 10$ is greater than $x\mapsto x$ on $(-\infty,10]$ but $0<1$. The slope is a variation and has nothing to do with the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g'(x)$ always less than $f'(x)$ implies (if the two are continuous) that $g(x)$ is always increasing at a lesser rate then $f(x)$ (or decreasing at a greater rate, or decreasing when the other is increasing or holding steady).

If, at some point, $f(x)$ is greater than $g(x)$ the difference is just going to get larger and larger as $x$ gets larger. (But also not that at earlier values of x the gap was less).

If, on the other hand, g(x) "starts" out larger at some point $x$, the gap is going to get smaller and smaller.  Likely $f$ and $g$ will intersect and afterwards $f$ will be larger the $g$.  If so, there is only one possible point of intersection and after $f$ will always be larger.

But also possible is that the gap gets smaller and smaller but never actually becomes zero.  A good example of the is $f(x) = 1 - 1/x$ on $(0, \infty)$ and $g(x) = 1$.  $f'(x) = 1/x^2 > 0 = g'(x)$.  $g(x)$ "begins" at 1 and stays at 1 forever.  $f(x)$ "starts" at "damned near -$\infty$" and spends "its entire life" trying to "catch up".

Your functions... well, you forgot the "plus a constant" refrain.  $f(x) = x + C_1$ and $g(x) = \frac{(x + 1)^{(1-a)}}{1-a} + C_2$.  The gap, $f(x) - g(x)$ between them is $(C_1 - C_2) + x -  \frac{(x + 1)^{(1-a)}}{1-a}$.  This gap is increasing.  If it "began" at a negative value when $g(x) > f(x)$ the gap will eventually increase to zero (and $f(x) = g(x)$ ["$f$ finally caught up"]) then increase to a positive value ($f(x) > g(x)$).

Comment: Ah. I guess my mistake was assuming I could discard the portion of the curve where x is negative? I was thinking that the integral would start from 0 and go to whereever, rather than also including that part of the function.

Comment: Sort of.  $f'(x) > g'(x)$ means nothing more or less than the rate of change of f at any instant is greater than the rate of change of g.  Doesn't say anything about what the actual values of either are at any instant.  We *can* conclude f(h) - g(h) < f(2h) - f(2h) < f(3h) - f(3h).  But we don't know anything about f(0) compared the g(0).

Comment: Suppose Gus if 45 years old and has been working at a low paying job for 30 years.  He has a lot more moneyy than Frank who just graduated from law school with 75,000 student debt and is just beginning his career as a very high paid lawyer.  Gus has more money than Frank right now but F' = franks salary is much higher than G' = Gus' salary.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if we have a derivable function $f$ then $f+c$ also has derivative $f'$.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about the integration constant.
$f(x) = x + C_1$ and $g(x) = \frac{(x+1)^{(1-a)}}{1-a} + C_2$

> If a function's derivative is less than some other function's at all points, how can that function ever be greater than it?

There's nothing weird about that.

Also, $g(x)'$ is bigger than $1$ for some negative $x$

Comment: That's why I wrote: (to the right of the y-axis, of course). I thought that wouldn't matter, which was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the derivative of a function at any given point is not related *in any way* to the value of the function at that point. Antiderivatives are only defined up to a constant. What this means is that given any differentiable function $f(x)$ and any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f_c(x):=f(x)+c$ has derivative $f_c'(x)=f'(x)+0=f'(x)$. So "the" antiderivative of $f'(x)$ can take on any value you wish at any given point of $\mathbb{R}$.

It sounds like maybe you're thinking about antidifferentiation as area accumulation, and reasoning that if we accumulate area under a smaller function then we get a smaller total area. This is true. If $g'(x)\leq f'(x)$, then $\int_0^x g'(t)\ dt \leq \int_0^x f'(t)\ dt$. The problem is that those integrals do not evaluate to $g(x)$ and $f(x)$, respectively, but rather $g(x)-g(0)$ and $f(x)-f(0)$. So you *do* obtain the inequality $g(x)-g(0)\leq f(x)-f(0)$. For your example functions, $f(0)=0<\frac{1}{1-a}=g(0)$, so you cannot deduce that $g(x)\leq f(x)$, but rather only $g(x)\leq f(x)+\frac{1}{1-a}$.